# Opening and place, any screen in the first application plan with Appcelerator

Tags: android, mobile, appcelerator

For example:

I'm using the Y application, but with the X in the background, make a open a specific screen of the X application (through a hardware feature) and it opens the application, but I can only see when returning to the application X that was in the background, need when you run the 'open' is also allowed to focus the X application and as result of which the Y into the background.

```
var controller = Alloy.createController("MyControl");
var view = controller.getView();
view.open();
```

I'm using and following the Appcelerator documentation. https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/156087/get-view-controller.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I read your questions 3 times but I don't get it, sorry. You want one Android app to open another and then show a specific screen? You will need to use URL schemes - http://fokkezb.nl/2013/08/26/url-schemes-for-ios-and-android-1/ - for that and read the URL used to open the second app and act accordingly.

Comment: What happens is this : I 'm developing an application that has a feature that accesses the Google Maps , making the application I'm developing stay in the background and bringing the map of Google Maps to foreground . I need a button is triggered when a hardware I can exit the google map and return to my application, thus making my application to foreground and background for google map . Remembering all this without iterating with the phone, will only be clicked a button on a hardware where I can throw a javascript event and treat the appacelerator .

Comment: That's what the Android back button is for. If the user presses that button Google Maps will close and your app will get focus again.

Comment: Perfect!I need to run this android behavior with Appcelerator, in a js function. Can you help me?

Comment: There's nothing you need to do for this. Just press the hardware/software back button when you are in Google Maps and it should get you back.